# How to show diff products and subcategory on custom taxonomy template?

Tags: wordpress

I have created custom post type named testimonial in admin and taxonomy named sesseion.I have multiple category and sub-cat in taxonomy.I am showing all parent and sub cat on home page.when user will click on sub cat then it needs to show all products of that sub category and when user will click on parent category then it needs to show all subcategory list.

I have create a custom template named "taxonomy-sesseion".But when i click on parent and sub cat then it redirects to that template.Do i need to add a condition on the same template to show diff listing according to parent and sub cat?

This is code to get the listing of products on custom taxonomy template.

```
$posts_array =
    array(
        'posts_per_page' => 16,
        'post_type' => 'testimonials',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'sessions',
                'field' => 'term_id',
                'terms' => $term->term_id,
            )
        )
    );
$query = new WP_Query($posts_array); 

if ($query->have_posts()) : 

while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); 
$thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($max_value[$i]->post_id);
$thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id, 'large', true);

endwhile; 

else:
echo "No Record";   

endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect sub categories to another template like "sesseion-index.php"

```
global $wp_query;
$taxonomy = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
if ( $taxonomy->parent!=0 ) {
    // do required actions
    include(TEMPLATEPATH .'/sesseion-index.php');
}else {
get_header();
//etc.
get_footer();
```

add this code to "taxonomy-sesseion.php" and you can display list of sub categories there and testimonials on "sesseion-index.php".